# IE focus event randomly fails after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, dom-manipulation

Currently, we're only supporting IE8.

I have an ajax call that gets data from the server, replaces the HTML in a container div with the response, then attempts to focus's in on an element contained in the response.

Depending on [IE Magic]? sometimes this code works, sometimes it doesn't.  I need to find something that can work 100% of the time.  The console.log statement logs the correct ID 100% of the time, even when the focus fails.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: that.Url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: dataToSend,
    success: function (response) {
        $(container).html(response);
        that.initialize();

        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        setTimeout(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                console.log($(element).attr('id'));
                                element.focus();
                            }, 10);
                        }, 10);
                    }, 10);
                }, 10);
            }, 10);
        }, 10);
    }
```

The nested setTimeouts were there to see if maybe something else was being put on the stack during an earlier timeout.  I tried it with a single setTimeout set to 1000, and was still seeing random failures.  I've tried replacing `$(container).html(response);` with `$(container)[0].innerHTML = response;` and that still doesn't work consistently.  I've tried replacing `document.getElementById(element)` with `$(container).find('#' + elementId)`.  I've also tried moving `var element = document.getElementById(elementId);` into the setTimeout and am still seeing random failures.  Using Firefox, 0 of the setTimeouts are needed and the code runs flawlessly, however that's not an option for us unfortunately.  Changing `console.log` to `alert` does fix the issue, but only because it delays the focus until after 'ok' is clicked but that extra mouse click is awful for usability.

`that.initialize()` adds classes to new elements, adds events, modifies the widths/heights of new elements, etc... and all of that works 100% of the time.

Comment: Is `initialize` introducing anything like timeouts that manipulate the DOM after the fact?  Does the injected HTML contain scripts that cause side effects?

Comment: I see that this is a really common problem, with most of the solutions using a timeout.  Another site claims that calling `.focus()` twice in a row always works.  I don't have an old IE to test with, but give that second option a whirl.

Comment: Thanks Jacob!

So far doing the focus twice in a row works best.  I'll have to test it some more but I haven't seen a failure yet.

Comment: Cool, I'll post as an answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a true bug in older IEs.  One trick that reportedly works is to call `.focus()` twice in a row.

Comment: Wow, thanks. This broke for XP IE for me after an update (worked in post-XP IE compatibility modes), and I kept undoing code changes but could not pinpoint what sprung it. This fixed it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `$(element).focus()` instead of `element.focus()`? `focus` is a jQuery method, which must be invoked on a jQuery object.

Comment: $(element).focus() is the jquery method to focus into a jquery object, while element.focus() is the javascript method to focus in on a DOM element (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp).  I've tried both and neither work consistenly in this case.